# CAPSPageMenu get the index when we press in menu taps

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have added a CAPSPageMenu. The current index is always 0. 
I want to know the index of the menu item I tap on.

I tried below code but when I add the breakpoint to this delegate method it is not called.

I'm using this lib : https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu/blob/master/README.md

```
class firstVC: UIViewController,CAPSPageMenuDelegate {

    var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pageMenu?.delegate=self
    }

    func willMoveToPage(_ controller: UIViewController, index: Int){   
        print(index)
    }

    func didMoveToPage(_ controller: UIViewController, index: Int){
        print(index)
    }

}
```

Update :

```
@IBOutlet var optionView: UIView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            var menuTitleFont: UIFont?
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 568 {
                menuTitleFont = UIFont(name: "roboto-Bold", size: 10.0)
            }
            else {
                menuTitleFont = UIFont(name: "roboto-Bold", size: 12.0)
            }


            let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
                .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.yellow),
                .viewBackgroundColor(UIColor.black),
                .selectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.white),
                .bottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor.lightGray),
                .selectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.white),
                .unselectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.lightGray),
                //.menuItemFont(12),
                .menuHeight(50.0),
                .menuItemWidth(self.view.frame.size.width/10 + 30),
                .centerMenuItems(true)
            ]
            print(pageMenu)
            pageMenu!.delegate = self

            var controllerArray = [UIViewController]()

            if  let AllVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"AllVc") {
                AllVc.title = "AllVc"
                controllerArray.append(AllVc)
            }


            if  let baseVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"baseVc") {
                baseVc.title = "baseVc"
                controllerArray.append(baseVc)
            }




            pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width:view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)



            self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
            self.optionView.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

            pageMenu!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
```

this is my full viewdidload updated code.

Comment: Where is `pageMenu` initialised? - at the moment it looks like `pageMenu` is `nil` try `print(pageMenu)` after you set the delegate to see if this object exists.

Comment: @Wez i updated my full code .What i am doing wrong

Comment: i did `print(pageMenu)` its `nil`

Comment: Thanks I can see whats wrong here, have answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate **after** you initialise your CAPSPageMenu.

```
pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width:view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
pageMenu!.delegate = self
print(pageMenu)
```